# Is Ethereum a decentralized or distributed blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ether

Is Ethereum a decentralized or distributed blockchain? I read the documentation but I can't understand.

Comment: Hi there. How are you defining each of those terms?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks, Hi I am reading the documentation and looking online. I've read that the blockchain is distributed and each node has a copy of the ledger but why is Ethereum a decentralized platform?

Comment: have you read this?[The Meaning of Decentralization](https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/the-meaning-of-decentralization-a0c92b76a274) .This is a very detailed answer by Vitalik Buterin himself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which consensus mechanism you are using: PoW/PoS is decentralized, PoA (especially with one generating node) is distributed.

Comment: I mean the blockchain is distributed and each node has a copy of the ledger but why is ethereum a decentralized platform?

Comment: "Decentralized" means that there is no node in the system, the shutdown of which will lead to the termination of the functioning of the entire network as a whole.